# How do I get Skype for Business presence cards on a non-SharePoint wiki?

Tags: presence-indication

My company uses SharePoint, Lync, the full Office 365 package. But on our SharePoint wikis, pretty much everything (i.e. scripting, Web Parts etc.) is disabled. However, we still have a non-SharePoint wiki installation, that supports HTML and JavaScript on its pages.

Is there an easy way to get a Skype/Lync/SharePoint Presence card (with photo and status indicator) displayed outside of SharePoint?

I would like to create a contact page for our team, and have names, photos and status indicators displayed.

I'm not an admin, however, so I can't configure or install any additional software, and I'll have to guess any URLs I need (e.g. to talk to a Skype server) if I can't look it up in the HTML source code of a served SharePoint web page...

Is there a way to do what I want to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript to call the plugin.

```
    <script language:" javascript">
    var nameCtrI = null; 
    $(document) . ready (function () {
        try {
            if (window. ActiveXObject) {
               nameCtrI = new ActiveXObject("Name.NameCtrl");
            }
            else {
               nameCtrl=CreateNPapiOnWindowsPlugin("application/x-sharepoint-uc");
            }
        catch (ex) {}
    });

function CreateNPApiOnWindowsPlugin(b){
  var  c=null;
  try{
    c=document.getElementById(b);
    if(!Boolean(c) && Boolean(navigator.mimeTypes) && navigator.mimTypes[b] && navigater.mimeTypes[b].enablePlugin){
      var a = document.createElement("object");
      a.id = b;
      a.type=b;
      a.width = "0";
      a.height = "0";
      a.style.setProperty("visibility","hidden","");
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      c = document.getElementById(b);
}
  }catch(d){
    c=null;
  }
}


    </script>
```

You can use HTML to build out your contact card and use the above for presence info. 
View the original reference by Jonathan Vanderoost here:  http://jonathanvanderoost.com/2013/12/09/integrate-lync-2013-presence-in-a-sharepoint-apps/